# How do I delete a collect with the shopify_api gem?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am having problems deleting a shopify collect:

```
collect =ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(:first,:params=>{:collection_id=>coll,:product_id=>id})
puts collect.json
collect.destroy
```

gives me the following error:

> activeresource-3.2.12/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:134:in
>   `handle_response': Failed.  Response code = 403.  Response message =
>   Forbidden. (ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess)

I see the collect data but I just cant delete it
this is a private app - any tips?

Comment: Do you have permission to delete this resource?

Comment: since it is a private app, i was under the impression that i have permission to do everything - but it does look like a permission issue

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: i dont remember - i ended building a custom solution with mongo and maybe sinatra i dont remember  - the functionality around collections when i was using it was a bit funky

Answer (score 0):

You can only destroy a Shopify Collect if its product and collection exist.

```
ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(1)
=> #<ShopifyAPI::Collect:0x007f243b896d8 @attributes={"id"=>7324445889, "collection_id"=>348881937, "product_id"=>2333862593, "featured"=>false, "created_at"=>"2015-09-19T16:28:50+01:00", "updated_at"=>"2015-09-19T16:28:50+01:00", "position"=>32, "sort_value"=>"0000000032"}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>

ShopifyAPI::CustomCollection.find(348881937)
=> ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound 404

ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(1).destroy
=> ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess Exception: Failed.  Response code = 403.
```